# why does this python program print True

Tags: python

```
x=True
def stupid():
    x=False
stupid()
print x
```

Comment: ok follow-up, how can I reference the outer x?

Comment: wow, someone answered that before i asked it  :)

Comment: Now replace `x=True` with `x = [1]`, and replace `x=False` with `x[0] = 2` and run your code again..

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You don't need to declare a function-local variable in Python.  The "x=False" is referring to an x local to stupid().  If you really want to modify the global x inside stupid:

```
def stupid():
    global x
    x=False
```

Comment: Note that if you did the `print x` inside the function it would use the global `x`.  It's only *assignment* that creates the new local variable.

Answer (score 10):

To answer your next question, use `global`:

```
x=True
def stupid():
    global x
    x=False
stupid()
print x
```

Answer (score 6):

Because x's scope is local to the function stupid().  once you call the function, and it ends, you're out of it's scope, and you print the value of "x" that's defined outside of the function stupid() -- and, the x that's defined *inside* of function stupid() doesn't exist on the stack anymore (once that function ends)

**edit after your comment:**

the *outer* x is referenced when you printed it, just like you did.

the *inner* x can only be referenced whilst your inside the function stupid().  so you can print inside of that function so that you see what value the x inside of it holds.

**About "global"**

- it works & answers the question, apparently
- not a good idea to use all that often
- causes readability and scalability issues (and potentially more)
- depending on your project, you may want to reconsider using a global variable defined inside of a local function.

Answer (score 5):

If that code is all inside a function though, `global` is not going to work, because then `x` would not be a global variable. In Python 3.x, they introduced the `nonlocal` keyword, which would make the code work regardless of whether it is at the top level or inside a function:

```
x=True
def stupid():
    nonlocal x
    x=False
stupid()
print x
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to access the global variable x from a method in python, you need to do so explicitly:

```
x=True
def stupid():
    global x
    x=False

stupid()
print x
```

Answer (score 2):

The x in the function stupid() is a local variable, so you really have 2 variables named x.

Answer (score 2):

Add "global x" before x=False in the function and it will print True. Otherwise, it's there are two "x"'s, each in a different scope.

Answer (score 2):

- Because you're making an assignment to `x` inside `stupid()`, Python creates a new `x` inside `stupid()`.
- If you were only *reading* from `x` inside `stupid()`, Python would in fact use the global `x`, which is what you wanted.
- To force Python to use the global `x`, add `global x` as the first line inside `stupid()`.